# Jest - How to run .each in parallel

Tags: jestjs

I'm currently using test.each, anyway to run them in parallel instead of synchronously?

```
test.each`
  searchEngine                      |  keyword          | urlToVisit 
  ${'https://google.com/?num=100'}  | ${'aol'}          | ${'a[href="https://www.aol.com/"]'}         
  ${'https://google.com/?num=100'}  | ${'aol'}          | ${'a[href="https://www.aol.com/"]'}          
`('should search on google and navigate to domain', async ({
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been available since Jest 26.3 (via https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/9326).

```js
test.concurrent.each([
  [1, 1, 2],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [2, 1, 3],
])('.add(%i, %i)', async (a, b, expected) => {
  expect(a + b).toBe(expected);
});
```

https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testconcurrenteachtablename-fn-timeout